# How to play streamed audio in background on Android?

Tags: android, media-player

I have an Android application that plays streamed audio from the Internet using the `MediaPlayer` class.

> How do I let it continue to play the audio on the background when the
>   user hits the home button to run other applications?

While running other apps, I'd like it to continue to play the audio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use something called Android Services.

From the docs:

"A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use."

Here's the excellent official guide to using services to get you started:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Here's a good tutorial on building an audio player:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Here's a video tutorial for building a streaming music player:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKL-efbiIAM

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to implement a Service in order to play media in the background without it being tied to the Activity that started playback. Have a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices).

Comment: Thanks for the hint on Services and for the link!

Answer (score 2):

The key is define [Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) to continue playing in background:

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        myMediaPlayer.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

> [Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) : if this service's process is killed while it is 
>   started the system will try to re-create the service.

This is an example of to do this:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by jorgesys.
 */

/* Add declaration of this service into the AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag*/

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jorgesys_song);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

**Start service:**

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(myService);
```

**Stop service:**

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
stopService(myService);
```

**[Complete code of this example.](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background)**

Comment: I'm not sure if this code still works nowadays for the background limitations since Oreo, please refer to 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: if this service's process is killed while it is started... then the media stops playing